# PostgreSQL CASE: position within text array

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, case

I am currently successfully using a CASE expression to update an empty column based on attributes from other columns. For example

```
UPDATE table SET cat = CASE 
WHEN term = '{"Boulder"}' then 'Boulder'
```

However, I need to do the same but on an text array and particularly when an element is in a specific position within that array.

For example if the data looks like

```
{"Boulder, Tree, Bush"}

WHEN position('Tree' in term) > 0 then 'Boulder'
```

But I receive an error message

function pg_catalog.position(character varying[], unknown) does not exist

I have used position in a function before so I am not sure why PostgreSQL does not like it in this situation.

Is there a way to using a CASE expression whilst determining the position of a text element within an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently your `term` column is defined as an array, e.g.  `varchar[]`. The `position` function only works with scalar values, not with arrays.

If you want to test if an element is contained in an array you need to use a different operator: `@>`

```
update foobar
   set cat = 'Boulder'
where term @> '{"Boulder"}'
```

The expression `'{"Boulder"}'` creates an array with a single element. It's equivalent to `array['Boulder']` (which I find more readable). So the above `where` condition updates all rows where the array `term` contains all elements of the array on the right hand side of the operator. In this case it's only a single element you are testing for.

More details about the array functions and operators can be found in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

**Edit after the requirements have changed**

To find and update only those where boulder is in the first, second or third place, you can use this:

```
update foobar
   set cat = 'Boulder'
where 'Boulder' in (term[1], term[2], term[3]);
```

Comment: Or you can use `WHERE 'Boulder' = ANY (term)`. It is easier to read. Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html). Part '8.15.5. Searching in Arrays'.

Comment: Hi a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for your answer but it will find Boulder anywhere within the array. I am trying to find out if Boulder sits first, second or third in the array. Hence why I was trying to use position.